# Specify values for X-axis and Y-axis ticks and control their format

Tags: plotting, formatting

I have following problem:

I want to set the values for the X-and Y axis by myself, but the values (e.g. 0.800) are not plotted as I defined them (see image 0,8), mathematica removes the zeros.

```
Data = {{58.771, 0.792}, {53.532, 0.801}, {48.083, 0.795}, {57.343,0.794524}};
AxisY = {0.795, 0.800};
AxisX = {48, 53, 58};
ShowLegend[ 
  Show[
    {ListPlot[Data]},
    Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
    FrameTicks -> {{AxisY, Automatic}, {AxisX, Automatic}}
  ],
  {{{Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], "ABC"}}}
]
```

[image]

I tried to solve this problem with *NumberForm*, but that does't work, the Y-axis disappears. SetPrecision doesn't work in my case, because I don't want to set total positions, I want to set positions after decimal point. Have someone an idea to solve this problem with an easy way?

```
ShowLegend[ 
  Show[
    {ListPlot[Data]},
    Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
    FrameTicks -> {{NumberForm[#, {4, 2}] &@{Axisy}, Automatic}, {Axisx,Automatic}}
  ],
  {{{Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], "ABC"}}}
]
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9.0

Comment: Your way will not work because `NumberForm` is not a `Number`. But if you take a closer look at `Details & Options` for `Ticks` you will see that the fast fix would be to put there `{#, NumberForm[#, {4, 3}]} & /@ AxisY`.

Comment: Oh man, thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You can force these ticks as follows

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
ticksy[min_, max_] := {{0.795, "0.795"}, {0.800, "0.800"}};
ticksx[min_, max_] := {{48, "48"}, {53, "53"}, {58, "58"}};
Data = {{58.771, 0.792}, {53.532, 0.801}, {48.083, 0.795}, {57.343,0.794524}};
ShowLegend[Show[{ListPlot[Data]}, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{ticksy, Automatic}, {ticksx, 
     Automatic}}], {{{Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], "ABC"}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or can use a formatting function instead of string like this

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
padIt2[v_, f_] := AccountingForm[v, f, NumberSigns -> {"", ""}, 
   NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}, SignPadding -> True];
ticksy[min_, max_] := Table[{i, padIt2[i, {5, 4}]}, {i, min, max, .001}];
ticksx[min_, max_] := {#, padIt2[#, 2]} & /@ {48, 53, 58};
Data = {{58.771, 0.792}, {53.532, 0.801}, {48.083, 0.795}, {57.343, 0.794524}};

ShowLegend[
 Show[{ListPlot[Data]}, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{ticksy, Automatic}, {ticksx, 
     Automatic}}], {{{Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], "ABC"}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can also use `NumberForm` as the second argument (second list position or w/e) instead of string.